# Plotting points from external file in GIMP

Tags: gimp, script

I've got to believe someone has written a SCRIPT-FU scriptor or simple plug-in that reads a file of (x,y) points (in GIMP's coordinate system) and plots small circles of specified color and diameter at those locations in the current layer (or similar functionality that I could adapt), but a quick search doesn't turn anything up. Can someone please help me?

Comment: why do you have the photoshop scripting tag?

Comment: tell me how to turn it off, and I will!

Comment: You can press edit and remove it, but i have fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using python scripting you just need:

```
gimp.set_foreground(*color)
pdb.gimp_context_set_brush_size(dotSize)
pdb.gimp_paintbrush_default(layer,2,[x,y])
```

where `[x,y]` is a two-elements vector with the coordinates of the center of the dot.

Since this is Python, you have all the Python power to read your coordinates form whatever file you have: flat text, csv, xls, ods, xml, yaml...

Comment: Then accept the answer :) (not begging for kharma, but answers without upvotes/acceptation keep being popped up by bots...)

Comment: I'm a total newbie...I looked for a link to click to do just that. Where is it?

Comment: Ah...just found it!

Comment: Actually you only "upvoted". To "accept" there is a grey "V" check mark under the votes count (that you can only see on questions you asked)

Comment: Got it! Thanks! (and thank you for the original answer--I'm rolling along very nicely now.)